# What is the purpose of setting a CLASSPATH in Java?

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I just installed Java on a Mac for the first time (jdk 10.0.2 SE) and I'm on macOS 10.13.6.  I just created a basic Hello World program in my home directory, compiled it and ran it, but I have nothing set on my CLASSPATH environment variable except for the current directory "." My question is how am I able to compile and run this program?  How is it finding the classes from the Java library?  I've always assumed I need to set this variable, and I have it set to my jdk installation directory in Windows.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-5F4A0659-BFC5-4CB9-9920-D2DEABF29894 this may help.

Comment: I would kindly suggest you to change the question as it doesn't meet your explanation

Comment: @Raj It didn't, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHY DO WE SET THE CLASS-PATH?

CLASSPATH is an environment variable and contains paths to the jar files and path to various packages.

KISS ANSWER TO YOUR QUERY:

Perhaps the reason behind successful execution of
your code is that the JVM checks the current directory
first for the perception of jar files and then follows
the classpath. So your current directory has those files.

Oh, you may wonder then why would we set the classpath. Setting the classpath overrides that by default path.

Comment: So is there any reason to set it other than convenience of finding class files in directories outside the current directory?

Comment: Nope.To get a clear cut idea refer http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

Let start with [sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehu5l.png) example why we must set class path in Java

If you see this example in the image, sample program converting List to Map

1. Created new ArrayList, and Map, using streams converting list to map.

ArrayList & Map are ADT (abstract datatypes) it came from as part of JDK
we're make using them.

If see carefully, In our application we imported those. (These classes are available in out JDK installation location)

When you install JDK, Under JRE[core classes files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRnu5.png), these all core .class files will be available as rt.jar.

When we compile our actual code, it depends on (ArrayList class and Map class). If you didn't tell(by setting path) these class are available in a particular location(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\jre\lib).  JVM can't read those dependencies.

That's why its mandatory to set class path in java.

As simple as that :-)

Comment: To help with readability and search discovery, please put your code samples embedded as text in the document rather than as linked screenshots.